# Issue with setting default Value for DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, default-value

I have a model in which I can not set [DefaultValue] for DateTime, the object is used to generate a list of users from the powershella script. When I do not have default value and powershell return null this causes an error.
I would like to make the date set to 01.01.1990 00:00:00 in the case of null

```
public class user
        {
            [DefaultValue("")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            //[DefaultValue( )]
            public DateTime PasswordLastSet { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Isn't it better to make DateTime nullable? Before you set the password for the first time, initial value might be null. public DateTime? PasswordLastSet { get; set; }

Comment: How about `[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(typeof(DateTime), "1900-01-01")]`

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use a constructor?

```
public class user
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime PasswordLastSet { get; set; }

    public user()
    {
        PasswordLastSet = DateTime.MinValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you on C# 6.0+ you can use property initializer for this: `public DateTime PasswordLastSet { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;`

Comment: You cant use `DateTime.MinValue`  in a SQL Server `DateTime` field beacuse `SQL Server` has a MinValue of `1753`.

Comment: @vasily.sib so what, the currect way to do this is by constructor, not attribute

Comment: You should use `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue` if this will be linked to SQL `DateTime` column.

Comment: @Afnan Ahmad thats not the point of the question... sql, mysql, i don't care(it works for mysql)

Comment: @AfnanAhmad you know, there is [DateTime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql), right?

Comment: @omriman12 agreed.

Comment: @omriman12 it's ok. Your answer is seems valid as for me. My comment - is just a side note.